# Can I change the color of the current date in Mavericks Calendar?

Tags: ical, macos

Unlike previous versions of Calendar, Mavericks Calendar uses a color to indicate the current day. This color clashes with many of the colors I've been using for years for various calendars (and is even the same as one I use for one of my calendars), which makes the appointments for the current day almost unreadable.

Is there a way to restore the neutral, light gray used to indicate the current day used in earlier versions of Calendar?

Comment: I'd just like to make it a darker color, if possible.  Ony my screen it's really hard to make out which day is highlighted.

Comment: @JamesAlday: Anything but pink, really.

Comment: Did you ask at bugreport.apple.com ? They may give you some tricks (I had a problem with the dock and they gave me an useful advice to solve it)

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say that after examining the plist for 10.9 Calendar.app I don't even see a way to change the color via command line. Sorry good sir but I gave it my best.